# App is not installing in Ipads in codenameone

Tags: ios, codenameone

App is installing in all devices(android,iPhone5 and iPhone6) except Ipads, don't know what went wrong. I added UDID correctly and i added ios.debug.archs=armv7 also for 64 bit architecture but still its not installing in iPad.

This is the error coming when installing the build on the ipad

```
LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: <private>
MyIpad-iPad SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[49] <Error>: Applications did fail to install: ("<LSApplicationProxy: 0x67b6fd0> com.mypackagename.myapp (null) <com.mypackagename.myapp <INVALID >> {820C60EF-9814-402A-935F-08A4EE5AFB68 620}") (appInfos: (null))
MyIpad-iPad UserEventAgent(MobileCoreServices)[22] <Error>: LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: <private>!B23:com.mypackagename.myapp,J:5279861597988946299,I:-989713608027401512#[<private>]: Failed to install application at path: <private> error: <private>
MyIpad-iPad appstored[128] <Notice>: !B23:com.mypackagename.myapp,J:5279861597988946299,I:-989713608027401512#[<private>]: Install failed after error: <private>
```

if any one have idea please let me know where i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just added the UDID, an updated provisioning profile is required

Comment: ya i added updated provisioning profile then also same issue..

Answer (score 0):

There is a post here that lists all of the common points of failure: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/my-ios-build-wont-install.html

Notice that if it's running iOS 11 and is a 64 bit device it won't accept a 32 bit app.

Also notice that if you got the UDID from an application it's the wrong UDID.

Comment: its not application UDID i've picked it from iTunes and i added ios.debug.archs=armv7  is this help to run in 64 bit device?

Comment: No. It sets the mode to 32 bit. Remove that build hint. If you are running on iOS 11 it won't allow 32 bit apps anymore

Comment: i removed it but still not installing in iPads and whether its there are not no matter app is installing in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6..

Comment: If you have access to a Mac try the tip mentioned with looking at the console while installing to provide you with a hint. This might also be related to your settings. Notice a UI element in our iOS section of the settings allows you to limit the app to iPhone only or tablet only so make sure you didn't unintentionally select that option

Comment: sorry for late reply shai.. actually i tried to find the option(iOS section of the settings allows you to limit the app to iPhone only or tablet) but i didn't find any where..

Comment: It's under Right Click -> Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> iOS Settings -> Project Type (should be ios not iphone)

Comment: I would suggest going over the list I provided one by one and if all else fails you will need a Mac to see why the install is failing in the device console. Paste the output of the console here and it should indicate what is wrong.

Comment: Hi shai, I tried all but those all are ok and finally i got the mac and got the error and added in the question..  please check it ..

Comment: It looks like you cut out some important details from the install log. I'm assuming you replaced parts of the package with `<private>` which is fine but I think you might have cut something out or might have had a mistake there. Make sure your app id matches that prefix. You can see the app id in the Codename One Settings -> iOS Signing section.

Comment: sorry shai i forgot to add 'codename1.arg.ios.debug.archs=armv7'.. after adding this it is installing in iPad and remaining devices but not installing in iphone5.. don't know why?

Comment: If it's iphone 5S running a new OS version it would require a 64 bit build

Comment: yes its iphone 5s.. if i remove `ios.debug.archs=armv7` flag then its installing in iphone 5S but then its not installing in iPad so what to do now to  install same build in all devices..

Comment: We only support one architecture in debug builds, you will need two releases since Apple killed support for 32 bit in newer OS's.

Comment: for release builds we cannot release two builds know so what to do for release builds?

Comment: I said: "We only support one architecture in **debug** builds". Release builds include both architectures and would work everywhere.

Comment: should i need to add for release like below  `codename1.arg.ios.debug.archs=armv7`..

Comment: No. We always include both 64 & 32 bit binaries in the release. Notice you can't install the release builds, you can only upload them to Apple